# What does the name of the struct timespec from the C standard library stand for?

Tags: c, struct, time, libc, time.h

As in the title, what does the name of the `timespec` struct in `time.h` from the C standard library stand for?

Is it a "time specification"?

If yes, then what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the name of the timespec struct in time.h from the C standard library stand for?

Time specification.

> Is it a "time specification"?

Yes.

> If yes, then what does that mean?

Looking at [oxford specification meaning](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/specification) and also of time, a "time specification" or `timespec` structure in this context means:

A C language description of how something is or can be measured in seconds and nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the first question, we can say yes briefly. You can access the time structs shown below with #include <time.h>.

timeval, timespec, itimerval, itimerspec, bintime -- time structures

In response to the second question
The time () function sends the time in seconds from 01/01/1970 to the date and time the program was running. Its general statement is as follows:

```
time_t time (time_t * time);
```

time_t is a numeric type (usually long int) that represents time information.
time is a pointer type variable that holds date information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code at / usr/include/linux/time.h :

```c
struct timespec {
  __kernel_time_t tv_sec;
  long tv_nsec;
};
```

This should be what you want.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I'm asking about the meaning of `timespec` and not about its definition. Thanks for the answer anyways.